# Bootstrap 5 form-group, form-row, form-inline not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to update my app from Bootstrap 4 to Bootstrap 5, but all the elements that were using  form classes such as `form-group`, `form-row`, `form-inline` are completely broken.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The reason is `form-group`, `form-row`, and `form-inline` classes have been removed in Bootstrap 5:

> Breaking change: Dropped form-specific layout classes for our grid system. Use our grid and utilities instead of .form-group, .form-row, or .form-inline.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#forms

So [Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/) and [Utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/utilities/) are supposed to be used instead.

...but if you are looking for a quick solution, here's how these classes were working in Bootstrap 4:

```css
.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.form-inline .form-control {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.form-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -5px;
  margin-left: -5px;
}

.form-row > .col {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

label {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
```

Comment: Deducing from this answer, you can also apply classes d-inline-block and w-auto on any form-control to achieve form-inline effect.

Comment: @Francesco Borzi - the css classes u added  ( form-group, form-inline , etc ) will simulate them in a Bootstrap 5 environment ? Hope u can add more ... This will  greatly help migrating to v5 ...

Comment: yes, they simulate them in a Boostrap 5 environment. I'm using them for this project to mine after migrating from v4 to v5: https://github.com/azerothcore/Keira3

I don't currently plan to add more classes

Comment: But _which_ grid and utilities classes?

Comment: @OrangeDog wish they'd provided nearest equivalents in their migration guide. Based on this answer it looks like .form-group is roughly equivalent to mb-3:

.mb-3 {
  margin-bottom: 1rem !important; }

Answer (score 34):

## How to migrate an `.inline-form` to Bootstrap 5+

### TLDR:

1. Replace the Bootstrap 4 `inline-form` class with flexbox helper classes: `d-flex flex-row align-items-center flex-wrap`.
2. If you used the `mr-*` class to space your form elements, replace these with the equivalent `me-*` classes ("margin end"). E.x. `mr-2` becomes `me-2`. Similarly, `ml-*` becomes `ms-*` ("margin start").
3. Consult the [Bootstrap 5 form documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/forms/overview/) to migrate your input elements. For example, on a select element the class `custom-select` in v4 becomes `form-select` in v5.

### Full Example

Compare the Bootstrap 4 inline form below with the exact equivalent form in Bootstrap 5.

#### Example (trimmed) from Bootstrap 4's docs ([Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bootstrap-4-inline-form-example-4euk37)).

*This is Bootstrap 4 code.*

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <label class="my-1 mr-2" for="inlineFormCustomSelectPref">Preference</label>
  <select class="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelectPref">
    <option selected>Choose...</option>
  </select>

  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox my-1 mr-sm-2">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customControlInline">Remember my preference</label>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary my-1">Submit</button>
</form>
```

#### Same form in Bootstrap 5 ([Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bootstrap-5-inline-form-example-065utx?file=/index.html:517-1341))

```
<form class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center flex-wrap">
  <label class="my-1 me-2" for="inlineFormCustomSelectPref">Preference</label>
  <select class="form-select my-1 me-sm-2 w-auto" id="inlineFormCustomSelectPref">
    <option selected>Choose...</option>
  </select>

  <div class="form-check my-1 me-sm-2">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="customControlInline" />
    <label class="form-check-label" for="customControlInline">Remember my preference</label>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary my-1">Submit</button>
</form>
```

### What to do with the deprecated `form-group`, `form-row` and `form-inline` classes in Bootstrap 5

As others have mentioned, the classes `form-group`, `form-row` and `form-inline` are removed in Bootstrap 5. Here's how they can be replaced:

- `form-group` can be replaced with `mb-3`, since it previously applied the property `margin-bottom: 1rem` which the `mb-3` class [will do by default as well](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/).
- Form specific layout classes are dropped ([source: Migration guide](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#forms)). `form-row` can be replaced with `row` in most instances.
- As described above, `form-inline` can be recreated by applying the following classes: `d-flex flex-row align-items-center flex-wrap`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: inline-form tags were a lifesaver.  Perfect replacement for what I needed.  Why didn't BS just hire you to write their migration column...

Comment: `form-group` to `mb-3` was exactly what i was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The fix is easier than this. Wrap all your rows in `<div class="grid">`, then change `class="form-row"` to `class="row"`, and convert `class="form-group col-md-3"` (for example) to `class="col-md-3"`.

Comment: [CSS Grid system is experimental and opt-in as of v5.1.0](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/css-grid/). enable the CSS Grid by setting `$enable-cssgrid: true;`

Answer (score 1):

Because form-group, form-row, and form-inline classes have been removed in Bootstrap 5:
**I have resorted to using gy-. eg(gy-2)**

```html
<div class="card">
   <div class="card-body">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-lg-2 gy-2">
               <select class="form-control">
                   <option>invoice</option>
                   <option>qoutation</option>
               </select>
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-2 gy-2">
               <select class="form-control product-select" name="state">
                   <option value="AL">Search Product..</option>
               </select>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```