# upgrading bootstrap changed form styling

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have Django forms with crispy forms. I upgraded from bootstrap 4.0 to the latest version 5.1.3. I correct most of the changes but I cant figure out why the form styling has changed.

[image]

[image]

You can see the spacing between the form fields has greatly changed. How do I go about correcting this to look like bootstrap 4.0

code:

```
    <div class="loginout-section">
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Log In</legend>
            {{ form|crispy }}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="login-register-btn" type="submit">Login</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="border-top pt-3">
        <small class="text-muted">
            Need An Account? <a class="ml-2" href="{% url 'register' %}">Sign Up Now</a>
        </small>
        <div class="inline">
            <small class="text-muted">
                Forgot Password? <a class="ml-2" href="{% url 'reset_password' %}">Reset Password</a>
           </small>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Update:

If I setup the forms similar to the docs and manually render the fields I can get it to look as expected.

code:

```
<div class="mb-3">
  {{form.username | as_crispy_field}}
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
  {{form.password | as_crispy_field}}
</div>
```

However one of the forms i have has about 200 fields it doesn't seem possible to wrap each field in a `<div class="mb-3"></div>` still looking for a proper solution

Answer (score 0):

based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67655096/bootstrap-5-form-group-form-row-form-inline#:%7E:text=1%20Answer&text=The%20reason%20is%20form%2Dgroup,grid%20and%20utilities%20instead%20of%20.) `form-group` and related elements have been removed. This is the code they used

```
.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.form-inline .form-control {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.form-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -5px;
  margin-left: -5px;
}

label {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
```